# Lucene/Solr: facet an already faceted date field (pivot facet / tree facet / sub-facet / hierarchical facets)

Tags: date, solr, facet

I am completely lost in a world of links and Solr terms. I currently have a date field which i facet, but i would like to face it 'further' if possible.
An example:
Field: date
Field: language

So if i run this query:

```
http://host:port/solr/select/?q="Don Quijote"&sort=date+asc&facet=true&facet.date=date&facet.date.start=2010-09-01T00:00:00Z&facet.date.end=2010-09-04T23:59:59Z&facet.date.gap=%2B1DAY&facet.field=language&facet.mincount=1&start=0&rows=10
```

I get 2 different faceted fields:

One for 'date' like

2010-09-01 (10)

2010-09-02 (4)

2010-09-03 (60)

2010-09-04 (7)

etc

and one for 'language'

'English' (23)

'Spanish' (34)

'French'  (32)

So my question is: How can i merge the 'language' field results into daily stats?
I want at the end something like this:

2010-09-01 (10)

```
'English' (4)

'Spanish' (5)

'French'  (1)
```

2010-09-02 (4)

```
'English' (1)

'Spanish' (1)

'French'  (2)
```

2010-09-03 (60)

```
'English' (20)

'Spanish' (20)

'French'  (20)
```

2010-09-04 (7)

```
'English' (2)

'Spanish' (3)

'French'  (1)
```

Is this possible? I've lost myself in terms like pivot, tried the `facet.tree=date,language` 
approach and i'm not sure if what i'm looking for is the 'hierarchical facet'...
Any pointers or guidance (but most of all, and example of how to do this with dates) will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Some links read:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-792

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-64

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Hierarchical-Facets-td474308.html

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Hierarchical-faceting-td1123548.html

http://www.craftyfella.com/2010/01/faceting-and-multifaceting-syntax-in.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if date facets can be used in the facet.tree patch. If you haven't that many languages (or dates) you could simply index the fields in one field via

```
'date/lang'
```

and then facet on that one field only via facet.field=date_lang_merge_field

Comment: seems like a good option, though quite a resource demanding one... i'm keeping my hopes (and googleing skills) up in case i can find a way to make this work...

Comment: In case someone is looking for something similar, this option does indeed increase the size of our index in case you got a quite a mount of dates, but does however result in records per day. Since apparently Solr doesn't provide this functionality yet... all I did is create a new field as suggested by Karusell and indexed like:

2010-09-01 - (LanguageValue)

This, once faceted, resulted in the results per day, per language.